# What word or short phrase could be used to describe 'sharing an activity, task, job or burden to lighten to load'?

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions, phrase-requests

I specifically need it to be neutral or positive in tone.

Comment: What about **help**?

Comment: Please note that although I have provided an answer, your question could be improved by editing it to include a sample sentence or two illustrating how you intend to use the word or phrase.

Comment: Writing advice requests are out of scope.
Word or phrase requests are out of scope, unless they are expert-level, particularly interesting, unique, and thought-provoking, and show effort and research.
For an introduction to the site, take the [Tour]. For help writing a good question, see [ask].

Comment: Please edit your question after looking over the [question checklist for single word requests](http://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info).

Answer (score 3):

I don't have a single word, but there is a well-known idiom:

> [Many hands make light work](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/many-hands-make-light-work): A large task does not seem as daunting when it is shared among multiple people.

Here, the "hands" represent the people's hands who help to perform the work, similar to "lend a helping hand," and the "light" work refers either to weight or intensity.

Answer (score 1):

To quote T.A. Webb, and assuming a broad definition of 'phrase':

> A burden shared is a burden halved.

Answer (score 1):

A well and truly neutral word would be [***cooperation***](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/cooperation). Nothing in there about lightening the load though.

> The action or process of working together to the same end:
> *they worked in close cooperation with the British Tourist Authority*

Reference:
http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/cooperation

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the context/subject, I would consider the following:

1. pitch in
2. lend a hand
3. contribute
4. chip in
5. cooperate (in agreement with Bookeater above)
6. collaborate

Comment: A suggestion is not an answer.
We're looking for long answers that provide explanation and context. A good answer is complete and explains why it is right, ideally with citations. Answers that lack support may be removed.
For an introduction to the site, take the [Tour]. For help writing a good answer, see [answer].